# Background Image repeating in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to apply a background image for a button inside the form. The code work and seems perfect in all browsers (Chrome, FF, Opera and Safari). But, in IE8(the only version i have checked), the image is getting repeated. I am trying to follow standard and simple HTML and CSS but this is really annoying. Please see the picture below

[image]

Following is the HTML

```
<div id="header">
            <div id="TopHead">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="/" alt="eyaas">
                        <img src="logo.gif" alt="eyaas" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="country">India | Rest of the World
                </div>
                <div id="linksAndSearch">
                    <div id="linksTop">My Account | Login | Register | Cart
                    </div>
                    <div id="searchBar">
                        <form id="search_mini_form" action="" method="get" class="search"> 
                            <div class="searchBox"> 
                                    <input id="Text1" type="text" name="" class="searchBoxDefaultText jsSearchTerm jsToggle" value="" /> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="searchButton"> 
                                <button type="submit" title="" class="searchBoxSubmitButton" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div> 
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="TopNav">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Following is the CSS

```
#linksAndSearch { float:left; }

.search { width:393px; height:35px; background-image:url('SearchBoxGrayFrameText.gif'); }

.searchBox { float:left; margin:6px 0 0 65px; background-image:url('SearchBoxFramed.gif'); width:275px; height:23px; overflow:hidden; }

.searchBox .searchBoxDefaultText { width:257px; height:19px; margin:2px 0 0 5px; font-size:15px; color:#CCC; }

.searchButton { float:left; margin:6px 0 0 10px; } 

.searchBoxSubmitButton { width:29px; height:23px; background-image:url( SearchSubmitBtnYellowArrow.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Some similar bug: http://haslayout.net/css/Float-Squeeze-Duplicate-Last-Character-Bug Is your IE running in IE8 or IE7 mode (and/or whatever else compatibility modes it has)?

Comment: I am running IE8 in normal mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by

```
<button type="submit" title="" class="searchBoxSubmitButton"/>
```

to

```
<button type="submit" title="" class="searchBoxSubmitButton"></button>
```

**Can someone elaborate on the issue as to why this was happening ?**

Comment: because button is a non-void element and needs a closing tag

Answer (score 1):

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

u refer this site, i think its may be useful for you,